# HLS with CDN token - iOS

Tags: ios, token, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm developing an iOS app which is able to download **m3u8 videos** and play it **offline** according to the `iOS 10` latest feature **Offline HLS**.

I'm trying to protect as best as I can `HTTP Live Stream` format videos on our **CDN**.

Each video has multiple bitrates so the `HLS` files consist of a master m3u8 manifest which points to several sub manifest files which in turn point to `ts` files (transport stream).

So I need to append this CDN token to the URLs of master m3u8, sub manifest m3u8 and `.ts` files. The token will be valid for 60 seconds, so it needs to get refreshed and the current token should get append with the URL.

How can I do this?

I tried this, but its appending to only master m3u8.

**My Code :**

```
    var components = URLComponents(string: playUrl)
    let token = URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: CDNTokenManager.getCDNToken())
    components?.queryItems = [token]
    let url = components?.url
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url!)
    let downloadTask = downloadURLSession.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: asset,
                                                             assetTitle: "title",
                                                             assetArtworkData: nil,
                                                             options: nil)
    downloadTask?.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, iOS doesn't offer anything to modify the URL in the m3u8 files. It will retrieve them without any changes. So I don't think you can solve this entirely on the client side.

In addition to your client side code, you will also need to implement a web app on the server side that generates the m3u8 files on demand and adds the CDN token.

For example, the iOS client requests the master file at https://cdn.com/master/fk29x8.m3u8?token=12345, the web app dynamically generates the file containing URLs like https://cdn.com/sub/fk29x8-1280x720-1823.m3u8?token=12345. This URL is again served by the web app and contains URLs like https://cdn.com/stream/fk29x8-1280x720-1823/mp4-123.ts?token=12345.

So the web app's task is basically to read a template file and replace the token value with the on given in the requested URL.

Comment: The token needs to get refreshed for the security means. So how this will work?

Comment: Is there any way to track the URL requests, and modify them by inserting token at the client side?

Comment: I've heard of solutions where the app additionally works as an HTTP proxy server. The proxy server can then modify the responses. I can't tell if this is still possible on iOS and how it would be done.